# updating the new values in the services

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rxjs

When you click open first window button a popup opens,which contains a text box. When we copy the URL in the popup and hit save it saves sample pdf in the grid, but when i refresh it disappears.

Is there anyway can I permanently save it in the grid by updating in the grid?

My code is as follows, and also available as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qfuasv4/).

```
$("#save").click(function() {
    grid.dataSource.add({ "FileName": $("#fname").val(), "ThreeDots": "Last Name" });
    $("#fname").val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value of `#fname` which never gets updated.  The file input is here is `#batchFile`.

Also, you probably want to strip the path from the value, and get the file name only.  You can do so with

```
.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '')
```

See it here:  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rf4uscr/).

```
$("#save").click(function() {
    var f = $('#batchFile').val();
    f = f.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, '');
    grid.dataSource.add({ "FileName": f, "ThreeDots": "Last Name" });
 });
```